# I dont have overload for EF savechanges, and no acceptallchanges available

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I am very confused, i am trying in vain to queue up multiple inserts i have thousands of adds to do so i only want to really do the database once.

I am using .net 4 and entity framework 4 and also added reference to system.data.objects
but i still have no overload available for SaveChanges

here is my code:

```
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            using (myDbContext context = new myDbContext)
            {

                foreach (var p in model)
                {
                    var tempProduct = new Products();
                    // set a loopable list of available products
                    IEnumerable<MerchantProductFeedMerchantProd> prod = p.prod;

                    foreach (var i in prod)
                    {
                        var prodText = i.text.FirstOrDefault();
                        var prodUri = i.uri.FirstOrDefault();
                        var prodPrice = i.price.FirstOrDefault();

                        FillTempProduct(feedId, i, tempProduct, supplierId, feedInfo, prodPrice, prodText,
                                        prodUri);


                            context.Products.Add(tempProduct);
                            context.SaveChanges(false); // no overload

                }


                scope.Complete();
                context.AcceptAllChanges(); //acceptallchanges not referenced ??

            }
        }
```

this is really battering my head now, so any help would be much appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 7):

Because you are using DbContext API and these methods are from ObjectContext API. DbContext API is simplified = it is only for simple requirements. If you have more complex requirements you must use ObjectContext API by converting your `DbContext` to `ObjectContext` instance:

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)myDbContext).ObjectContext;
```

Comment: Hi, this does not work, if i just use the above i get a moan about myDbContext needing to be a property.  so to myDbContext i added an objectContext property  and then used this:  using (ObjectContext context = new myDContext().ObjectContext())   but i dont know how to add to it now context.AddObject("Products", tempProduct);  ERROR:  The underlying provider failed on Open.

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Comment: latest, EntityFramework.4.1.10715.0 i use MvcScaffolding, and its pulls the latest EF from nuget